# Icon of webapps not visible when used outside the site

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, icons, favicon

I am not in the webapps beta, and now my browser cannot download http://sstatic.net/wa/favicon.ico , something it want's to do on other area51 stackexchange proposals (next to a user that is in the beta)

Maybe lift the access restrictions on this icon? Or not show this icon yet when it is in very private beta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in Area 51.

Comment: Whoops! Fixed now